# Is there a file for each socket?

Tags: files, kernel, socket

"Everything is a file" in the UNIX World.

Above sentence is famous. When I run `echo "hello programmer" >> /dev/tty1` , I can watch the given string on `TeleType 1`  , ....

What and where is file per each `socket`? Suppose my friend connects to my PC, and its IP is `h.h.h.h` , how can I access the respective file? Is it possible?

Comment: The socket API is actually a deviation from the "Unix policy" in this regard, because it originally came from [BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). Note that there's always [Plan 9 from Bell Labs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) which is "more Unix than Unix" – even the network and graphics APIs are files there.

Comment: sockets and processes are mentioned a fair amount in Plan 9 papers, mostly talking about where the UNIX model went wrong.

Comment: *"Everything is a file" in the UNIX World.* TLDR: [That's not true](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html).  Read that carefully and note how POSIX clearly and consistently differentiates between **files**, **file descriptions**, and **file descriptors**.  And note well how [the value returned from `socket()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) is a **file descriptor** that's not associated with any **file** nor **file description**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

man 7 unix:

> The AF_UNIX (also known as AF_LOCAL) socket family is used to communicate between processes on the same machine efficiently. Traditionally, UNIX domain
>   sockets can be either unnamed, or bound to a file system pathname (marked as being of type socket). Linux also supports an abstract namespace which is
>   independent of the file system.

I.e. not every socket can be seen as a file (in the sense of "no file without a file name").

But there are files with lists of sockets (e.g. `/proc/net/tcp`); not exactly what "everything is a file" means, though.

Comment: ***This*** is the correct answer.  See my comments above and on the most-upvoted answer.

Answer (score 47):

A socket *is* a file. But not all files have names. Here are a few examples of files that don't have names:

- Any file that used to have a name, and is now deleted, but is still opened by a program.
- An unnamed [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), such as one created by the `|` shell operator.
- Most [sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket): any [Internet socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket), or a [Unix socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) which is not in the filesystem namespace (it can be in the abstract namespace or unnamed).

Files such as unnamed pipes or sockets are created by a process and can only be accessed in that process or in subsequently-created child processes. (This is not completely true: a process that has a pipe or socket (or any other file) open can transmit it to other processes via a Unix socket; this is known as [file descriptor passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909064/portable-way-to-pass-file-descriptor-between-different-processes).)

Sockets that have a name (whether in the filesystem or abstract) can be opened using that name. Network sockets can be opened (or more precisely connected to) remotely from any machine that has appropriate connectivity.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: `/proc/<pid>/fd/*` and `/proc/net/*` may be interesting

Comment: Please accept this answer. It is IMHO a lot more accurate.

Comment: @user1202136 This answer is not accurate. [POSIX specifically and consistently uses **file**, **file descriptor**, and **file description**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html): "The open() function shall establish the connection between a **file** and a **file descriptor**. It shall create an open **file description** that refers to a **file** and a **file descriptor** that refers to that open **file description**. The **file descriptor** is used by other I/O functions to refer to that **file**. The path argument points to a pathname naming the **file**."

Comment: The [POSIX `socket()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html) states:  "The `socket()` function shall create an unbound socket in a communications domain, and return a **file descriptor** that can be used in later function calls that operate on sockets."  Note well the **lack** of any **file** object associated with the **file descriptor** returned from `socket()`.  So no, "everything is a file" is not accurate.  "Everything is a **file descriptor**" would be much more accurate. Because not every **file descriptor** refers to a **file**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you're going to nitpick like this, “everything is a file descriptor” is also wrong: the correct statement would be “everything can be accessed via a file descriptor”. In the context of this question, there is no meaningful difference between “is a file” and “can be accessed via a file descriptor”. This is a question about operating system design, not about POSIX terminology.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' *This is a question about operating system design*  Agreed. 
 I don't have a problem with the gist of "everything is a file". I probably should have pointed out the reason I wound up nitpicking this is because your answer [was being used to support the idea that `open()` could replace `connect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68336836/could-we-use-open-as-an-alternative-for-connect-in-c-socket-programming#comment120774430_68336836), basically because "everything is a file".  Instead of supporting the concept, your answer was being used support specifics.

Answer (score 14):

> What and where is file per each socket?

"Everything" is an exaggeration.  It's not a strict policy, it's just a common practice to use the filesystem for interfaces since filesystem access is synonymous with system calls (i.e., the filesystem is really an interface with the kernel, and so provides a convenient format for all kinds of things).  Other operating systems do not make as much use of this, so it is considered a distinguishing feature.

As Hauke Laging mentions, ["unix local" sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) have a file node as do named pipes (see `man fifo`).  However, internet protocol sockets (used for network communication) do not. Instead, they are associated in userspace with a port number.  Note that a server socket on a single port connects multiple clients each with their own individual socket (a single unix local socket file can be also be used this way with a server, meaning, there may be multiple sockets associated with the same file address) and in code they are in fact identified individually via separate numerical *file descriptors.*

So, in that sense all sockets *are* much like files, and have a link in `/proc/[pid]/fd/`.  You can even call `readlink()` on this inode and get a special sort of filename, which is used in command line tools such as `lsof`, I believe; likewise you can get information about the socket descriptor via `fstat()`.

Comment: You mean "identified in userspace by their inode"? Not every socket has a port number and there can be several sockets for the same port number (doesn't make sense, though).

Comment: @HaukeLaging : Good point. I've edited to make this clearer starting with the second paragraph.